# Getting BTC price on-chain

Tags: oracles

What good oracles there exist to pull BTC/USD price on-chain? E.g. Uniswap pools with enough liquidity, Chainlink data and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Right now for BTC/USD, you have Link, a WBTC uni pool, and then Tellor.